# Video stabilizer software for Linux

Tags: linux, video, gui, video-editing

I search a video stabilizer software.

- Input: Video in AVI/MPG
- Output: Same video, stabilized, in a common video format
- It should be easy to use. It is for my son - twelve years old.

Software for Linux is preferred, but Windows is OK, not mac.

Price/Licence: I am willing to pay up to 50$.

Answer (score 3):

Blender from blender.org and the software is free.

Blender exist for windows,mac,linux

numerous tutorials exists

[tutorial 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb6uGasYDMAhWnnYMKHQa9AlkQtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnU8zqn091rM&usg=AFQjCNEVwiJL8C8W_ZS0H4LgAJrrIabwRw&sig2=CQFHFPFzzaiyISC6tfM_gw&bvm=bv.119028448,d.amc)

google search **blender video stabilization**

There are a number of steps, and it is not a simple as click stabilize and d done.  However, if you are there just in-case he needs help the first couple of times he should get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

Hands-free Linux method, with **transcode**'s *stabilizer* filter.  A crude wrapper function, (Bourne shell, bash, etc.):

```
# Usage:  shakeless foo.avi
# eventually outputs stable_foo.avi
unset slow
# export slow="nice -n 19 ionice -c3 "  # uncomment if it the PC bogs down.
shakeless() { $slow transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i "$1" 2> /dev/null ; \
              $slow transcode -J transform -i "$1" -y raw -o stable_"$1" ; \
              rm "$1".trf ;  }
```

To use:

```
shakeless foo.avi
```

...which can take *hours*.  To display the time elapsed when it's finished, replace the previous line with:

```
time shakeless foo.avi
```

Once it's over, there should be a 'stable_foo.avi' file -- play that.

How is this not worse than **blender**?  No complex learning curve, no mousing, menuing, etc.  Maybe less hassle, even for a 12 year old user.

What it does, in two passes; first pass:

```
transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i foo.avi
```

...slow, outputs *many* status messages; after which there's a new big *foo.avi.tr* data file -- it's not video, it's intermediate data used for the second step:

```
transcode -J transform --mplayer_probe -i foo.avi -y raw -o stable_foo.avi
```

After which *stable_foo.avi* should be a less shaky version of *foo.avi*

Method above adapted from D. Isenmann's [Deshaking videos with Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119172641/https://isenmann.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/deshaking-videos-with-linux/).

Comment: What is transcode and where to get it?

Comment: @LEQADA, `transcode` is a video-manipulation program.  Finding a copy may be a bit hard, since it hasn't been updated since 2010.

Comment: On Manjaro/Arch Linux: "pamac install mplayer transcode" in terminal and then it worked, but ruined the audio.

Comment: @LEQADA, Not sure at present where to find `transcode` in 2022, (not on Ubuntu), but if it is unavailable,  the video stabilizer library  used by `transcode` is called *vid.stab* and can be found at the [*vid.stab* home page](http://public.hronopik.de/vid.stab/features.php?lang=en) or on [github](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab).  Todo: switching to another *vid.stab* frontend like `mplayer` or `ffmpeg` requires updating this answer's code...

Answer (score 2):

[OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) has got a stabilizer filter since [version 2.6.0](https://www.openshot.org/blog/2021/08/25/new_openshot_release_260/):

> New Computer Vision and AI effects (motion tracking, object detection, **stabilization**)

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8gSD-5bXfk) a video showing how it works: Drag the 'Stabilizer' filter to a video clip, then configure the 'smoothing window'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).